# Critical error on woocommerce checkout page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, errors, 404-error, order

I am facing an issue on my website. I am using woocommerce plugin with stripe payment method to checkout. I can checkout successfully on desktop/laptop and after that I can see Thankyou page.But when I place order from mobile device and checkout, I can't see Thankyou message after checkout process. Just seeing an error like attached screenshot. Can some one guide me what is the issue on mobile device?

Error on mobile
[image]

On desktop
[image]

Comment: this is a generic error, you need to look up your PHP error log to find out what the actual problem is, then ask about it in a WooCommerce community, 3rd party plugin questions are offtopic here